# How can I use ODBC connections with Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, odbc, .net-core-3.0

I use Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.1.

I want to use an ODBC connection in a .NET Core 3.0 project (the sample works with .NET Framework 4.x):

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnectionString))
{
    using (OdbcCommand command =  new OdbcCommand(sql, connection)) 
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        command.Connection.Open();
        string value = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
        return value;
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

Error   CS1069
The type name 'OdbcConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.Odbc'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.Odbc, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

I get a similar message for the OdbcCommand class and a similar error if I try the same with the class OleDbConnection.

In the Microsoft Documentation the class OdbcConnection is discribed as part of .NET Core 3.0 in System.Data.Odbc.

Why do I have to make a link to an older version?

How could I make the requested reference?

Addendum
I found out that the System.Data.Odbc package in .NET Core 3.0 only contains two classes (OdbcPermission and OdbcPermissionAttribute). All other classes included in System.Data.Odbc of .NET Framework 4.8 are missing.

Comment: The ODBC has to be defined in Control Panel : administrative Tools : ODBC DataSource

Comment: The problem is not related to the ODBC configuration of Windows. The problem ist a compiler error. The compiler does not know a class it should know according to the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: I may be the version in the .proj file.  Create a new project and add the System.Data.ODBC.  Then compile and open the .proj with notepad.  Check version and see if it is the same with non working project.  Then edit the non working project.

Comment: I have no .proj file, only a .sln file. I cannot find any version number related to ODBC in it. On the other hand the non working project is a new project, it is not imported from an older Visual C# version. Only the .c# files were added from the old project.

Comment: If you upgraded Net after the project was created you can have issue.  Does a new project compile with using System.Data.ODBC?

Comment: No, all classes in System.Data.Odbc except OdbcPermission and OdbcPermissionAttribute are missing.

Comment: Have you tried adding reference from menu : Project : Add Reference : Net : System.Data.ODBC

Comment: There is no menu item Net under Add Reference. I cannot find System.Data.Odbc in any part under Add Reference.

Comment: What about a TAB.  If you do not have System.Data.Odbc then try just System.Data without ODBC.  If that still doesn't work then use the Browse TAB and find ODBC  dll on your machine.

Comment: There is no odbc.dll on my machine. But please keep in mind, that ODBC is working with .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: The Project : Add reference show where the path and name of dll.  Check the name and location in 4.8.

Comment: I found in another stackoverflow case a comment where was said that .NET Framework has its ODBC modules in System.Data.dll and .NET Core (in this case 2.0) has its ODBC modules in System.Data.Odbc.dll. The first dll I have on my computer, but not the second. This may be an explanation. Do you have System.Data.Odbc.dll on your machine? Can you find the System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection class on your machine (just type system.data.odbc. in the editor an the class list will open)?

Comment: What I normally do to add a method is from edit menu search for symbol.  Then after I find which library the method is in add the using statement at top of module.  Sometimes I also have to add the reference to the library because no all methods are in the default libraries installed with VS.  On my PC ODBC is in System.Data.ODBC.  The libraries are namespaces and different versions of Net can pack the libraries/namespace differently.  I do not have ORACLE or MySQL but if I installed these libraries they would still be in the namespace System.Data. but in a different dll.

Answer (score 7):

The ODBC and OleDb functions are included in the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility Pack. If you download this with the help of NuGet, the classes are found (tested for .NET Core 3.1).

The package can be downloaded Here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Comment: +1 This was the issue in my case. `using System.Data.Odbc`, and `var conn = new OdbcConnection();` later on was throwing an error, untill I installed the package via package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 5+ you won't have odbc, or oledb without adding a nuget package.  Often you just need to switch from

`using System.Data.SqlClient;` to `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;`

And use a connection string like shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16)

```cs
// Use your own server, database, and user ID.
// User ID is optional.
string ConnectionString1 = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Encrypt=True; Database=testdb; User Id=user@domain.com";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1)) {
    conn.Open();
}

// User ID is not provided.
string ConnectionString2 = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Encrypt=True; Database=testdb";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString2)) {
    conn.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`dotnet add package System.Data.Odbc --version 8.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mark an accepted answer, and this is an older post.

I recently started working with Azure Databricks && SQL Warehouses, which offers an ODBC driver for use in dotnet. Perhaps this simple & insecure example will be of use to someone:

> xxx.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>console_to_bricks_sqlWarehouse</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Odbc" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

> Program.cs

```cs
using System.Data.Odbc;

string bricksConnectionString = "Driver={Simba Spark ODBC Driver};Host=adb-30-----.17.azuredatabricks.net;Port=443;HTTPPath=/sql/1.0/warehouses/9b10a-----972e95;ThriftTransport=2;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=dapi....";

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(bricksConnectionString))
{
    try 
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.");
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dev.users limit 10;";
        using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
        {
            using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}"); 
    }
}
```

Note: The connection details in this example are configured in the ODBC driver after installation.

You can find a little more information specific to dotnet & Azure Databricks SQL Warehouse [here](https://github.com/idusortus/dotnet-console-databricks-sqlwarehouse).