# ODBC in C# ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#

I have a DB2 database that can be accessed through ODBC in the `Server Explorer` in Visual Studio, but I am unable to access it in my ASP.NET Core net5.0 Api application with the `System.Data.Odbc` library.

I am currently using my ODBC connection string from the working connection in the `Server Explorer` in the following code

```
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from Employee",  
   configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
```

I get the following error

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.ODBC is not
> supported on this platform.    at
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter..ctor(String selectCommandText,
> String selectConnectionString)

If there is a way to use an ODBC connection string in an ASP.NET Core .net5.0 Api application please let me know.

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: Not tried, so let us know if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170947/how-can-i-use-odbc-connections-with-visual-studio-2019-and-net-core-3-0

Comment: There is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/898) if the ODBC connection is created in a .NET Standard library. Could that be the cause of your problem?

Comment: @Steve Thank you! It seems like it is an issue with not having the `System.Data.ODBC` in .net core. Unfortunately I get the same error with that solution.

Comment: "not supported on this platform" - on what OS are you trying this?

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks!! I asked in that thread, and they helped me out :)