ODBC connections C#
Trying to do tests with ODBC connections, using microsofts documentation and nothing is working, I'm eventually going to have to get code up and running that interfaces with an AS400 using ODBC, and maybe more, but I need to get the ODBC working first
Here's the code:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;


static private void InsertRow(string connectionString)
    string queryString =
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')";
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);

    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // The connection is automatically closed at
        // the end of the Using block.


What error do you get? Can you connect with the same connection string using another SQL tool?

for the first part, where I'm trying microsofts code and tweaking it, it's saying that OdbcCommand and OdbcConnection can't be found in the namespace System.Data.Odbc

at this point I talked to a few people at work and we're going to use sql, but im getting the same error

What version of .Net, are you using .Net Core 3.x - if so see this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170947/how-can-i-use-odbc-connections-with-visual-studio-2019-and-net-core-3-0

Honestly, I don't even know how to check, trying to learn and can't figure any of it out and work is having me do it

right-click the project and choose Properties, it should show there.

The following may be of interest: post

The following may be of interest as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950023/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425 (ODBC usage is similar to OLEDB usage).

none of this means anything to me, might as well just quit with it

Does anything in AS/400 connection strings help?

none of this means anything to me: Unfortunately, SO isn't a site for learning the basics. One needs to perform research to understand the subject matter prior to beginning programming. It seems that you haven't performed enough research yet, and it may be too early to post a question here.

How to connect to AS400 IBM i with ODBC in .Net
First, a short intro:

If you're new to .Net altogether: .Net is very powerful but has a certain learning curve. Try first to understand the philosophy behind .Net - There are different versions of it (more to that here), and there are also so-called Extensions. You see this at the bottom of the Microsoft help pages under the "Applies to" section. That may be important if you want to re-use your .Net code on non-Windows platforms, such as mobile, linux, or even AS/400 IBM i PASE (there is MONO for IBM i (albeit currently not maintained))
There is C# and VB.Net - Make your decision carefully. I find VB.Net much easier to use without loss of capability (my personal opinion only). The example code here is in C# because the OP's question was a C# question.
Contrary to RPG (or even COBOL), database I/O in other languages / ecosystems is very much characterised by function calls. Also, you will perhaps miss the comfort of being able to write SELECT * FROM F1 INTO :F1R putting all fields at once into a data structure; oh well ...

Preparations:

Make sure you have ACS (IBM i Access Client Solutions) installed on the computer that makes the ODBC connection to the AS400 IBM i. ACS contains the IBM i ODBC Driver. You can check this in the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator under the Drivers tab 

There is also a smaller bundle available from IBM called "IBM i ACS Windows
Application Package", which also contains the ODBC driver (there are also ones for Linux, Mac, and for PASE) - Look in the AS400 IFS Directory
/QIBM/ProdData/Access/ACS/Base, you
might find the install bundle there; otherwise you need an IBM ID to
download it. See this video here: Get an ODBC driver to access DB2
for i 

To use System.Data.Odbc, you need to install the .Net package (extension) System.Data.Odbc:

In VS, go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Packet Manager Console
Paste dotnet add package System.Data.Odbc --version 8.0.0 into the console and press enter. This will install the package; from now on you can use System.Data.Odbc in your .Net projects.


You need an AS400 IBM i ODBC Connection String. It is all documented here: IBM i ODBC Connection string keywords (IBM) and here: IBM i Access ODBC driver connection strings

For starters, use this one: "Driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};System=<AS400-Hostname or IP Address>;Cmt=0;Uid=<AS400 User Id>;Pwd=<AS400 Password>;"
Note that for using commit , the file on the AS400 IBM i needs to be journaled, otherwise you will get Error SQL 7008



This is the DDS for the file we will be using
                                    UNIQUE       
        R F1R                                    
          F1NR           6S                      
          F1NAME        30                       
          F1STATUS       1                       
        K F1NR                                   

followed by
CRTPF FILE(MyLib/F1) SRCFILE(MyLib/QDDSSRC) 

or in SQL:
CREATE TABLE MyLib.F1 
(
    F1NR     NUMERIC(6, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,                              
    F1NAME   CHAR(30)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    F1STATUS CHAR(1)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY  KEY(F1NR)
)
RCDFMT F1R;

Now we're ready for some coding.
(Other perfectionists forgive me for not using try/catch or using, I know, but this is only to show the basics)
Note that - contrary to some other code samples - I will not close the connection, rather maintain it throughout, because to initiate an AS400 IBM i ODBC connection is very slow.
Also note that I am using BeginTransaction() and Commit() i.e. commitment control statements in this example, but since I use CommitLevel.None, they will have no effect until CommitLevel is changed to something else. (One should use commitment control, but that's another story).
In VS, click the "Create a new project" big-button, make sure on the right hand side the dropdown boxes show C#, Windows, and Console, then push "Console App":

then enter the following code:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

enum CommitLevel : int
{                       /* AS400 COMMIT()  DB2 Classic Isolation Level */
                        /* --------------  --------------------------- */
    None = 0,           /* *NONE (*NC)     N/A No Commitment Comntrol  */
    ReadCommited = 1,   /* *CS             CS  Cursor Stablility       */
    ReadUncommited = 2, /* *CHG            UR  Read Uncommited         */
    RepeatableRead = 3, /* *ALL (*RS)      RS  Read Stability          */
    Serializable = 4    /* *RR             RR  Repeatable Read         */
}

class AS400ODBCExample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Counters
        int recordsInserted = 0;
        int recordsRead = 0;

        // AS400 Connection String
        string cnnstrAS400 = "Driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};" +
                             "System=MySystem;" +
                             "Cmt=" + (int)CommitLevel.None + ";" +
                             "Uid=MyUser;Pwd=MyPassword;";
        // Library name
        string curLib = "MyLib";

        // Create the Connection object
        //   plus three Command objects (only to be tidy)
        //   plus a DataReader
        //    and a Transaction Object.
        OdbcConnection cnnAS400 = new OdbcConnection(cnnstrAS400);
        OdbcCommand odbcCmdDelete = new OdbcCommand();
        OdbcCommand odbcCmdRead = new OdbcCommand();
        OdbcCommand odbcCmdInsert = new OdbcCommand();
        OdbcDataReader dataReader;
        OdbcTransaction traAS400;

        // Open (establish) the AS400 IBM i Connection
        cnnAS400.Open();

        // Give the odbcCmd Objects the connection
        // and Set current schema (= library) 
        odbcCmdDelete.Connection = cnnAS400;
        odbcCmdDelete.CommandText = "SET CURRENT SCHEMA = '" + curLib + "'";
        odbcCmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

        odbcCmdRead.Connection = cnnAS400;
        odbcCmdRead.CommandText = "SET CURRENT SCHEMA = '" + curLib + "'";
        odbcCmdRead.ExecuteNonQuery();

        odbcCmdInsert.Connection = cnnAS400;
        odbcCmdInsert.CommandText = "SET CURRENT SCHEMA = '" + curLib + "'";
        odbcCmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        // Our first SQL command is to clear our example table
        traAS400 = cnnAS400.BeginTransaction();
        odbcCmdDelete.Transaction = traAS400;
        odbcCmdDelete.CommandText = "DELETE FROM F1";
        odbcCmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        traAS400.Commit();

        // Next, we insert three rows of data
        traAS400 = cnnAS400.BeginTransaction();
        odbcCmdInsert.Transaction = traAS400;

        odbcCmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO F1 (F1Nr, F1Name, F1Status) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Clear();
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Nr", OdbcType.Int).Value = 1;
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Name", OdbcType.Char).Value = "Los Pollos Hermanos";
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Status", OdbcType.Char).Value = "A";
        recordsInserted += odbcCmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Clear();
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Nr", OdbcType.Int).Value = 2;
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Name", OdbcType.Char).Value = "Hamlin, Hamlin & McGill";
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Status", OdbcType.Char).Value = "C";
        recordsInserted += odbcCmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Clear();
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Nr", OdbcType.Int).Value = 3;
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Name", OdbcType.Char).Value = "Madrigal Electromotive GmbH";
        odbcCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("F1Status", OdbcType.Char).Value = "A";
        recordsInserted += odbcCmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        traAS400.Commit();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} Records inserted.", recordsInserted);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Now, we read the data and write it to the console window
        odbcCmdRead.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM F1";
        dataReader = odbcCmdRead.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

        Console.WriteLine("Data after Insert:");
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            recordsRead++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", dataReader["F1Nr"], dataReader["F1Name"], dataReader["F1Status"]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Records read.", recordsRead);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Finally, clean up.
        dataReader.Close();

        odbcCmdDelete.Dispose();
        odbcCmdRead.Dispose();
        odbcCmdInsert.Dispose();

        cnnAS400.Close();
    }
}

And - voila!


Well, that's all so far;
AS400 IBM i forever.
If you liked this post, feel free to accept it as answer - many thanks, all the best!

Thanks for your elaborate posting! Maybe I can draw from your experience... I have a Win10 computer where a .NET 8 program is not working with the IBM i ODBC driver, but a .NET Framework 4.8 program is working well. Are you aware of any such issues?
